# Stripe Checkout is not able to run in an iFrame. Please redirect to Checkout at the top level

Tags: html, iframe, stripe-payments

I'm trying to load a checkout.stripe in an iframe, but it doesn't work, I get this message:

> Stripe Checkout is not able to run in an iFrame. Please redirect to Checkout at the top level.

I read before that Stripe doesn´t allow this.

Does anybody knows if this is true?
Is there any official documentation?

I tried with the tag object, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Why would they lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, currently you must redirect your customer to the Checkout Session `url`.

However, there's a note on the [main Checkout docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) that suggest there is work being done on allowing an embedded option, so you should contact Stripe if you are interested in that.

[image]

**Update:** Looks like [Embedded Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=embedded-checkout) is now available to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up at this question when this error was thrown when integrating [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) end-to-end tests with Stripe Checkout. In `cypress.config.ts` you can enable [`experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments) and it will resolve this error. You can then use `cy.origin` to interact with Stripe Checkout:

```
    // UI button that redirects to Stripe Checkout
    cy.get("#checkout").click()
    // Origin wrapper for cross-origin e2e testing
    cy.origin('https://checkout.stripe.com', () => {
      // Continue your Cypress code here
    });
```